# Understanding layers in a web application

Tags: web-applications, architecture, layer

I am a UI developer and would like to understand various application layers like UI layer, Service layer, etc

Could you please explain in easy to understand terms what role each layer performs? Also how do you determine which architecture to use?

Please provide some easy online references if you can. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did a write up along the lines you're after [here](https://morphological.wordpress.com/2011/08/29/5-layer-architecture/).

> The 5-Layer Architecture is primarily
>   concerned with the logical and
>   physical partitioning of code into
>   packages which support reuse.
>
> As you can see from the diagram below,
>   it partitions the system into
>   (surprise!) 5 Layers.  Unlike a lot of
>   other architectures that focus on the
>   "main horizontal" layers (like the UI,
>   BL and DAL) the 5-Layer Architecture
>   formally recognises other parts as a
>   logical layer that deserves equal
>   recognition.  Please read the formal
>   description (link above) for a full
>   and proper introduction.

[image]

Answer (score -2):

well it very vast concept to be summarized here....but MVC is undoubtedly most important and famous architecture in web application domain.
V- view layer which is related to how data is presented to user.
M-model layer which specifies business model and logic. This layer can further be divided into sub layers:- most important ones:- service layer(all servicing code goes here) and resources layer for e.g. Database
C-Controller layer which acts as a glue between view and model layer. It is decision maker controlling the flow of application.

You can start with below link:-

> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller
>   In above wiki, there are many links for language specific implentation which you can further take it up.

Comment: MVC is an architectural pattern which makes no mention of layers; layers are an architectural style. MVC can be applied to a layered architecture, with different layers being identified as Model, View or Controller, but Model, View or Controller are not layers in and of themselves.

Comment: The question is about layering and the answer posted here is about MVC design pattern - where M,V & C are components that interact and are not an example of layering.